# Issue in Non English Language gets from Database

Tags: php, android, json, api

I want to send data from PHP to Android Phone. For API call i am using "REST"

in my PHP all my Characters are Non English Language(Tamil). so i am using utf-8 for inserting the Non English (Tamil) content on Database.

All the characters are inserting in DB, i am sending the data as json to Android. But my Problem in Android Development side while getting the json file they are getting all the characters are like Question Marks(???????).

I am new to this field, I don't know how to solve this error.

This is my PHP Script i used:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'DbConnect.php';

    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');    

    $response = array();


    if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

        switch($_GET['apicall']){


            case 'question':

                // i am get lesson and chapter name as request from application side ,i will match lesson and chapter and send question 
                $lesson  = $_POST['lesson'];
                $chapter = $_POST['chapter'];

                if(!isset($lesson) || !isset($chapter)){
                    $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = 'key and values is empty (or) wrong';
                http_response_code(404); 
                    }



                if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('lesson','chapter'))){
                    //getting values 
                 $lesson = $_POST['lesson'];
                 $chapter = $_POST['chapter']; 

                    //creating the query 


                 $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

                  $query = "SELECT que_desc,true_ans FROM question WHERE lesson = '".$lesson."' AND chapter = '".$chapter."' ";

                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                   // $user =array();
                    $i=1;

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        $question = $row['que_desc'];
                        $true_ans = $row['true_ans'];
                        $response['question'][$i] = $question;
                        $response['ans'][$i] = $true_ans;

                        $i++;

                    }


                         mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');


                         header('Content-Type: application/json');
                        echo json_encode($response , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
                        exit;


                }
            break; 



                default: 
                $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = 'Invalid Operation Called';
                http_response_code(404);

            }

    }else{
        //if it is not api call 
        //pushing appropriate values to response array 
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
            http_response_code(404);
    }

    //displaying the response in json structure 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);

    //function validating all the paramters are available
    //we will pass the required parameters to this function 
    function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

        //traversing through all the parameters 
        foreach($params as $param){
            //if the paramter is not available
            if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
                //return false 
                return false; 
            }
        }
        //return true if every param is available 
        return true; 
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ==  "GET"){
        $response['method_type'] = "wrong";
        $response['status'] = 0;
        http_response_code(404);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);

    }


    ?>
```

[This is my DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okbH1.png)
[response on Android side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keGNE.png)
Anybody Please help me to solve this Error. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i tried to google to solve the above problem,
every one told to use below code if it's a fully php page

```
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
```

if it is html page use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

when you use php and html ,you have to implement both mysql_query() function code and above meta tag

after doing all the above ,i have not found any solution ,after working few hours, 
To make it work in localhost (xammp) 
1.go to xammp dashboard click mysql config file
2.file name "my.ini" will opened paste the below code

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

it worked in local host

To make it work in SERVER :
In BIGROCK SERVER they blocked some file for security reason ask them to release the file . then try with above code .

because in bluehost Server above code worked for me . 
Tamil(non ENGLISH) content are display well in json format ,and i send json to Andriod ,

and the same is not worked in Bigrock server.
hope this one may help someone.